# Seeing html code in tooltips in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am parsing web service xml and populating a treeview in asp.net.  I'm trying to display one of the xml node attributes as a tooltip, but that attribute happens to sometimes have html tags in it.  I know there seem to be some custom tooltip stuff out there, but I don't have the time or the experience to play with those yet.  Is there no way to easily remove such code or translate it into the textual equivalent?  I know I can replace br tags with environment.newline, but I don't want to have to do this for every conceivable html tag that might be embeded in the content!

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your markup?  The tooltip is driven by what's in the html 'title' attribute, but most ASP.net controls don't directly set this, but rather one of their properties in turn sets it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTML Agilty Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is an HTML parser that can read HTML fragments - you can do that and then read the `InnerText` property of the top node. The effect will be a textual version of the HTML.